# World lighting doesn't affect objects with Eevee renderer

Tags: shaders, lighting

I want an object to be evenly lit with a flat color, but I can't achieve such result - scene lights work, but world color does nothing and I don't know any other way of adding an ambient light.

[Here's the file](https://pasteall.org/blend/df6fc53b54dd49fdac33a9d0bd65ea0c) with preview of how it looks like

(I've set the world background to bright purple to make it easier to notice the difference in case of some intensity setting affects it - like it was the case with my green point light)

Comment: If you want the object to have no shading just connect an rgb node directly into the surface. It won't have any shading without a diffuse or principled bsdf.

Comment: i want it to have shading, but also not be completely black if there are no lights shining in that direction.

Comment: You could try making it an emission object perhaps? So it will always be lit?

Comment: i see! yes, it works, thank you! althought editing the pseudo-lighting will be inconvenient whenever i'll have multiple objects with different materials. could solve that with drivers, i guess, but that's extra work no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

found out i could do this with baked lighting:

- in viewport shading dropdown settings have "Scene World" enabled;
- Properties - Render - Indirect Lighting - Bake Indirect Lighting;
- slightly inconvenient as it requires rebaking if changes to the background are made. otherwise works fine - i was expecting the baked lighting to break when objects gets transformed.

alternatively, increasing sizes of existing lights can help, but it realyl screw with the scene setup:

- have a Point, Sun or Spot light type
- set Power and Radius (or Strength and Anlge in Sun's case) to something large, like 50kW 50m
- Sun type looks smoothest
- it's not directionless and still leaves faces completely black if they're facing in opposite direction of the light, but it's better than nothing

if there's a better way - please let me know.